# Adding rows to gridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I want to add new rows after the inserted rows. I have a button that shows bootstrap modal with some DropDownLists and Textboxes. The button in modal on click should insert the data from modal to the table. The problem is that when i try to add new row it will replace current row. What im doing wrong? Here is sample of my code:
.cs:

```
protected void addTrip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dostawca = DropDownDostawca.SelectedValue.ToString();
        cel = txtCel.InnerText;
        krajZagr = "";
        kraj = DropDownKraj.SelectedValue.ToString();
        miasto = txtMiasto.Text;
        if(rbKraj.Checked == true)
        {
            krajZagr = "Krajowa";
        }
        if(rbZag.Checked == true)
        {
            krajZagr = "Zagraniczna";
        }

        if(cel=="" || miasto=="" || kraj=="" || dostawca=="" )
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowPopup2();", true);

        }
        else
        {
            if(gridViewTrips.Columns.Count == 0)
            {

                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("DO_KOGO");
                DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("CEL");
                DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("KRAJOWA_ZAGRANICZNA");
                DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("KRAJ");
                DataColumn dc5 = new DataColumn("MIASTO");

                dt.Columns.Add(dc);
                dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
                dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
                dt.Columns.Add(dc4);
                dt.Columns.Add(dc5);

                dr["DO_KOGO"] = dostawca;
                dr["CEL"] = cel;
                dr["KRAJOWA_ZAGRANICZNA"] = krajZagr;
                dr["KRAJ"] = kraj;
                dr["MIASTO"] = miasto;

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                gridViewTrips.DataSource = dt;
                gridViewTrips.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["DO_KOGO"] = dostawca;
                dr["CEL"] = cel;
                dr["KRAJOWA_ZAGRANICZNA"] = krajZagr;
                dr["KRAJ"] = kraj;
                dr["MIASTO"] = miasto;

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                gridViewTrips.DataSource = dt;
                gridViewTrips.DataBind();
            }





        }


    }
```

.aspx:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="gridViewTrips">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <asp:Table ID="TableTrips" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>Do kogo</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>Cel</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>Krajowa/Zagraniczna</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>Kraj</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>Miasto</asp:TableHeaderCell>

            </asp:TableHeaderRow>

        </asp:Table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>

        </asp:GridView>
```

EDIT: Now I see when I debug my project the IF what i have: "if(gridViewTrips.Columns.Count == 0)" after inserted one row shows me that I dont have any columns. Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

What about create GridView column first...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx

and then AddChild method?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx